# Crontab working for everything but rclone

Tags: cron, rclone

I am trying to get my rclone backups to run daily, but for some reason my cron executes everything but my rclone.

```
52 7 * * * rclone sync /home/piserver/homeassistant GoogleDrive:/homeassistant_partial_$((date +%A)|tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') -vv --exclude=/config/secrets.yaml --exclude=/config/home-assistant_v2.db --delete-excluded >> /tmp/cron.log
52 7 * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> /tmp/cron.log2
```

The echo command is working. So the time is correct. But no cron.log is being created for the first command and it is clearly not being executed (or not executed correctly at least).

The rclone command itself works when entered in the command line.

Does anybody see my mistake?
I also tried with `/bin/rclone` but that also did not work.

Thank you
Alex

Comment: can you check the path of your cronjob like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401621/479040)? Maybe make a quick script as a workaround similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/117989/1151435).